# Arithmetical or geometrical sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have some problem in sequence, especially when I want to find the general formula of 'not arithmetic and also not geometric' sequences.

If I already knew that the sequence is arithmetic sequence, I can easily find the formula for arithmetic sequence, such that finding the general formula from 2,4,6,8..

We can use the formula Un=a+(n-1)d and we got Un= 2+(n-1)2= 2n

Another way to find the formula is using geometric sequence, for example we want to find the general formula of 3,6,12,24,...

We can use the formula Un= ar^(n-1), and we got: Un= 3.2^(n-1)

But, how about this sequence?

1/3, 3*sqrt 3, 27,...

Is there any way to find the general formula? I think I cannot use the formula from arithmetic and geometric sequences.

Please show me the way, so I can understand every steps.
Thanks

Comment: What about combining the properties of the two types?  It looks like the first ratio is $9\sqrt 3$ and the second is $3\sqrt 3$.  What would the ratio to the next term be?

Comment: I think the next ratio must be -3(sqrt 3). But, how to combine both properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: a sequence $\;a_1,a_2,...a_n,...\;$ is

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\text{Arithmetic, if}\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;d:=a_{n+1}-a_n\\{}\\
(2)&\;\;\;\text{Geometric, if}\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;q:=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\;\;\end{align*}\;\;\;\text{is a constant not depending on}\;\;n$$

In case (1), we call $\;d\;$ the constant difference, and in (2) we call $\;q\;$ the constant ratio.

Take now your sequence, look at it closely and when you *suspect* it is either Arithm. or Geom. (or its consecutive differences/ratios) apply the above **and check** .

Comment: I've already tried, and has just got that the series isn't satisfy both conditions. So, what must I do now?

Comment: As written in abiessu's comment" the consecutive ratios (between second and first elements, between third and second, etc.) seem to fulfill the rule 

$$9\sqrt3\;,\;3\sqrt3\;,\;\sqrt3\;,\;\frac{\sqrt3}3=\frac1{\sqrt3}\;,\ldots$$

So our sequence is

$$\frac13\;,\;3\sqrt3\;,\;27\;,\;27\sqrt3\;,\;27\;,\;\frac9{\sqrt3}=3\sqrt3\;,\;\ldots$$

Can you see some pattern here?

Comment: the ratio between 1 and 2 term is 9*sqrt 3, between 2 and 3 is 3*sqrt 3, between 3 and 4 is sqrt 3, between 4 and 5 is (sqrt 3)/9. It seems the ratio is decreasing, but how to find the general formula from this condition?

Comment: If I have calculated correctly, I get a ratio sequence formula of $r_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=(\sqrt 3)^{7-2n}$.